# Yammer App - Is there a way to bulk authorize a Yammer App for all users on a Enterprise network?

Tags: yammer

I know this question has been asked before but it has not got any answers yet. Is there a way to bulk authorise a Yammer App for all users on a Enterprise network. I.e flag it as trusted so that users do not need to individually allow it?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

No. Individual users must indicate they trust they app by clicking the button. If you could automate it, everyone would do it, and the whole trust process would be pointless.